# For loop to create new objects in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to create new objects for each item in the column "category."

```
rs_ <- regular_season %>% filter(user_id > 0)
unique_categories <- unique(regular_season$category)

for (i in unique_categories)
  rs_[i] <- regular_season %>% filter(category %in% unique_categories)
```

I've tried to create a template object "rs_" that I would iteratively add to (it's essentially the dataset with a null condition on it, just so it doesn't simply rename the dataset). Can someone show me how to better do this?

I have looked at some other questions that suggest using other things like lists but (of course without knowing too much about R) for the number of items in the column, it doesn't seem like a for loop would terrible, and I've had some trouble figuring out how to use lists anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `assign`

```
for(i in unique_categories) {
      assign(i, regular_season %>%
            filter(category %in% i)
  }
```

---

Or another option is `split` and `list2env`

```
list2env(split(regular_season, regular_season$category), 
        .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun this is very helpful! The website won't let me accept your answer yet but I will accept it when it will allow me, in about 10min